# Stacking drywall sheets in the bed of a smaller pickup

Tags: drywall

I will be installing drywall in an out of state property and will be picking up from HomeDepot. I am planning out the trip and wondering how many sheets of drywall will be carried per load.

The truck I will rent is the "Standard Pickup" from Enterprise that says *Nissan Frontier or similar*.  Looking at the specs of that truck we have

- *44.4"*  "Cargo Bed Width between Wheelhousings"
- 61.4"   "Cargo Bed Widthat Floor"

https://www.caranddriver.com/nissan/frontier/specs

[image]

Given drywall dimensions of 48" x 96" I'm presuming from those dimensions that we could lay the drywall  *not quite* flat (since it's 48" vs 44.4" wheelbase) and just under three feet would dangle over the hatch in the back.  Note that I am only driving about 8 miles so I can go slower/more carefully.

Any idea how many drywall sheets would stack that way?  They are 1/2 inch each but then the hanging out back would likely limit the safe number.   I am bringing truck straps to help out.

Note: this question is more aptly about *hauling* and *delivery* than *drywall* but I do not have the reputation to add new tags.

Comment: If the pickup thing doesn't work out well, some modern minivans can handle a 4'x 8' sheet flat with all the seats down/out.

Comment: Why not rent a full size F150? Lightest payload version has payload of 1985 lbs.(and up to 3325 lbs.). 1/2" 'rock weighs about 1.6lb/sf, so about 38 sheets minimum in F150 vs. Frontier MAX payload configuration of 1460 only 28 sheets.

Comment: @NoSparksPlease Yea looks like i should do that.

Comment: Why not just get the local builder marchant to deliver?

Comment: @Walker  HD delivery is backed up solid two weeks and I want to get started sooner.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most small trucks have indentations or molded rails at the same level as the wheel arches which accept crosswise two-by lumber for just this purpose.

[image]

<sub>[image source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tacomaworld.com%2Fthreads%2Fwhat-size-plank-fits-in-the-bed-slots.45645%2F&psig=AOvVaw0va040vHXYeOjrVua6-TuB&ust=1618686835271000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CA0QjhxqFwoTCKjdmsS8g_ACFQAAAAAdAAAAABAU)</sub>

If yours doesn't, three simple platforms comprising said crosswise two-by and some legs should do fine.

```
 ___________________________________________
|___________________________________________|
| |                                       | |
| |                                       | |
| |                                       | |
|_|                                       |_|
```

I owned a classic 'Yota during some of the years I was a home builder. This worked well. You can't put 40 sheets in a small truck anyway, so the platforms don't need to be very robust. I even carried a modern snowmobile on mine.

Comment: This is how my father-in-law and I hauled sheets in a friend's pickup. We made a support to rest on the lift gate and the bed cover had two spots to hold 2x4s

Comment: If we take the truckbed you're showing how many sheets of lighter drywall - which is what I chose - would you go with?   I'd like to get 15 or so : is  that reasonable?

Comment: Load it until the rubber bumpers over the rear axle have about an inch gap. :D I'd think you could get 15, but watch that gap. If it gets tight the entire strain of road bumps is on the tires.

Comment: Be careful your braking distance may increase with a heavy load. Learned that when I loaded up my Jeep with too much hardwood flooring, fortunately just scared the daylights out of me.

Answer (score 7):

Many Home Depots have their own rental available, at a relatively reasonable rate. They are likely to have pickups designed to handle 4' x 8' sheet goods. With an 8 mile trip, you can probably load up, deliver and return within a base-line 1 hour time. Might cost a few $ more than a regular rental place, but if you *only* need it for the delivery and not for hauling debris, etc. then it may be the easiest solution.

In my area (Maryland), currently $ 19 for the first 75 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

If it's 44.5 inches between wheel housings then do not prop up your drywall on such a sharp point of contact.

Get yourself one sheet of 3/4 inch plywood and rest the drywall on top of that.

The one thing to note is a risk of collapsing the wheel house. I do not know how much weight it can take before it collapses.

Answer (score 2):

HomeDepot will deliver your drywall to the location for free more than likely.   Drywall is expensive to move around in their stores and it is often cheaper to just deliver it to you - sure there is a minimum.   But I have had big boxes deliver drywall 30-40 times at least.   Their trucks have forklift in back so even if you have a weird yard or things going on they can usually get close or right at house.   (they do not carry in house - or at least near me they don't)

Note:  I didn't understand this was a thing until I did it and not sure if this still exists.   But there are people who have special contracts with homedepot and if they negotiate your order (they usually make $100-200 for this) they can literally get each sheet at almost half store price.   I have saved 2-3k several times doing this - last time was about 2 years ago.

Comment: Thx - HD delivery is backlogged 2 weeks and I wanted to dig into the project sooner.

Comment: How would one find a person with "special contracts with homedepot?"

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica - this is a local thing.   But you can probably look on craigslist or search for home depot bid room + your city.   There are guys who specialize in contracting through the bid room and basically act as a salesperson for homedepot - they go out and get contracts.   I have done this with drywall the most because the margins are so high I get a huge discount no matter what.   An average order of 4k in drywall... i might pay 2200 plus 150 fee.    I am sure the guy I use does this many times a week and takes him 5 mins to work out numbers.

Comment: The good thing too is he gives me a link, I pay homedepot and they just magically deliver it as soon as they can.    I don't have to sit on the phone with 5 people to work out things.   Now I am not sure this is the most timely answer as I know a lot of material places are backlogged but I am sure this is about to end.